Replace target table data in a transaction without blocking select on INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
I am looking for the best way to update tables which have variable number of columns.  I would also like to hear suggestions on the best way(s) to update tables with a fixed number of columns in general.
For some background, our data warehouse is made up of staging tables that are updated on a CRON schedule from an ERP system.  I just need an efficient way to insert data from a source table to a target table that doesn't prevent selecting data from the target & source tables nor prevents selecting INFORMATION_SCHEMA views in the target & source databases while the query is running.
Currently, the process I am using is as follows:

Start a transaction with rollback functionality on failure,
Within the transaction, create a data load table exactly like the target table I want to update and select source data into it,
Remake the target table to account for potentially new columns,
Then finally switch the partitions between data load table and target table (ALTER TABLE data_load_table_name SWITCH TO target_table_name) to update the target table with new data.

The problem with this method: due to the target table being remade within the transaction, a database level lock is placed that prevents selecting INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES while the transaction is running the SQL code.  This code takes about 1-2 minutes to run.
To combat that, I am thinking that I need to have multiple transactions within the BEGIN TRY...END TRY block so that the lock is placed only during the short time I am creating the database objects.  However, I don't know if that would maintain the rollback functionality, which resets everything changed in the transaction if one part of the transaction fails.
SQL code is structured like this:
BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRANSACTION query_transaction;

    ... DDL and DML code for replacing data in target table ...
    
    COMMIT TRANSACTION query_transaction;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    
... raises errors if any are found ...

END CATCH;



I might try using a MERGE command to update the data instead of a rename.  It will take longer, but that combined with a SET ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED you shouldn't have locking issues.
If you are deadset on moving the tables around I might TRUNCATE the destination first to reduce the data load you have to work with ( this is a non-rollback-able event ).  Dropping a table with no data, and then renaming the original may be faster.

Why is #2 needed to be done in the transaction? Also, it's very suspect you need to add columns to the target table when doing data load.

@siggemannen thank you looking at this.  The table I am trying to update sources data from an attribute and values table, so each attribute attached to an item, and then we value associated with that item's attribute.  To use this for advanced filtering in Power BI applications, we have been using a pivoted version of this table so that we can select attributes that apply to an item group and then have that be a filter in a dashboard for data visualization purposes.  It is unlikely that a new attribute will be made, but I want to have this dynamic width functionality just in case.
